# Specman e: How the predefined sequence.item should be used?

Tags: specman, e

I have a sequence:

```
sequence bus_sequence using item=bus_item, created_driver=bus_sequence_driver;
```

When I try to drive an item using the next code:

```
    extend bus_sequence {        
        body() @driver.clock is only {
            do item;
        };
    };
```

I get a compilation error that `'bus_sequence' does not have a field 'item'`.
But when I add the field item to the `bus_sequence`:

```
    extend bus_sequence {

        !item : bus_item;

        body() @driver.clock is only {
            do item;
        };
    };
```

I get an error that `Field 'item' was previously defined`in the `sequence` statement line...
How can I approach the predefined `item` field? Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The predefined `item` field belongs to the `SIMPLE bus_sequence` subtype, so it can neither be added to the base type, nor be accessed via it. And a given sequence may be of a `kind` other than `SIMPLE`.